# C# Types that accept Indexing

Tags: c#, indexing

What are all the types that have built in indexing.  For example I know ICollection and IEnumerable do not, but I'd like a list of all that do.

Apart from the list, if anyone can supply that, my specific problem deals with indexing all x,y points on a grid, so I'd like to access the object at x,y through an index if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish instead. Us feeding you a list isn't going to make for a very useful question.

Comment: take the .net sourcecode and search for 'this['

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a quick examination on mscorlib, here are the results;
Under the namespace `System.Collections`;

```
ArrayList
BitArray
HashTable
IDictionary, hence all the implementations.
IList, hence all the implementations.
SortedList
```

Under the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`

```
Dictionary<T, T>
IDictionary<T, T>, hence all the implementations.
IList<T>, hence all the implementations.
IReadOnlyDictionary<T, T>, hence all the implementations.
IReadOnlyList<T>, hence all the implementations.
List<T>, hence all the implementations.
```

Also you have arrays.
But, I suggest that you use a custom class for your specific task.
You need to provide information on, what your Grid's element or object at x, y looks like. Is it up to the user? Is it something you provide?

Here is a simple generic approach.

```
class GridManager<T>
{
    private T[,] _matrix;

    public GridManager(int rows, int columns)
    {
        _matrix = new T[rows, columns];
    }

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            return _matrix[i, j];
        }
        set
        {
            _matrix[i, j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it it nice of you to answer the question, this will encourage people to keep asking bad/low quality/unclear questions. This question already has 4 close-votes and might even be deleted ... along with your answer.

Comment: I don't even know if this is 100% accurate. `Dictionary` for example, uses a key, not the index.

Comment: @DangerZone It is completely up to the user to decide what those "key"s mean. Keep in mind that both arrays and Dictionaries are one to one functions. The only difference with a Dictionary is that, it does not guarantee existance of your key (e.g you cannot define your domain).

Comment: @welrocken I think what he means it that in your case the possible indices are limited by the initial grid size. A dictionary expands dynamically by adding key-value pairs.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer I understand that this type of questions, when answered may encourage people to ask similar ones. But as for this instance, I don't think there is a simple and easy way for a beginner to do and get his/her answer. I don't think it is easy to get the list of Types that has Indexing operator (and as DangerZone says, index being position) implemented. You can't use search for this kind of task, that is my opinion. You definetely can't use Reflection, there is a logic behind the Indexing mechanism. You have two resources; library interfaces and MSDN. I've took my shot.

Comment: As per the Dictionary, the interface just defines the operator, the usage. It has indexing support, basically this is a very valid Grid class using Dictionary; class DictionaryGrid<T> : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>>
        {
            public DictionaryGrid(int rows, int columns) : base(rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                    Add(i, new Dictionary<int, T>(columns));
            }
        }
Edit: I forgot to add the inner Dictionaries keys, but that's just detail.

Comment: @welrocken Oh I agree, this is one way to do it. The problem is that this question is so vague that we don't know if this is what OP wants (it could be) - I just wanted to confirm, that DangerZone is absolutely correct in claiming that a dictionary and an array are fundamentally different things even if they both use indexers. Btw. indexers can actually be found via reflection (PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters) what they do under the hood ... well that's a bit more work.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer What I meant by one can't use Reflection is exactly what DangerZone said. By definiton and default implementation Dictinoary does not satisfy the needs of a Grid, or any other Indexed system. So that means you can't use simple Reflection to detect whether or not any given class implements indexing the way you want it. You would most probably write other assertions that would satisfy an Indexed system (like an Array). Well, other than listing some types in the library, I tried to supply a simple solution, that's why I am OK-ish with my answer. Thanks for the constructiveness

Comment: Thank you this was such a helpful answer and allowed me to solve the missing link in my project :)